# In Ansible, can I re-use a role like a subroutine?

Tags: ansible

Ansible v2.11

I install a lot of applications on a Windows target, and most of them follow the same routine - download, unzip, for example.

```
- name: Download the zip file
  win_url:
     url_username: user
     url_password: password
     url: "{{ some_url }}"
     dest: "C:\\temp\\{{ some_archive }}"
- name: Unzip the archive
  win_unzip:
    src: "C:\\temp\\{{ some_archive }}"
    dest: "{{ archive_install_dir }}"
```

Is it possible to re-use the above role in "other roles" where I just pass in the `some_archive` and `archive_install_dir` variables for example? I set up my roles so each one has its own Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_role_module.html) or [import_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_role_module.html#ansible-collections-ansible-builtin-import-role-module) to pull it in.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please elaborate per suggestion above? Thanks.